# Why console.log(obj) show structure of obj instead of return value of toString()

Tags: javascript

I have an object with the following structure

```
var obj = {
    toString: function(){ return "20" },
    valueOf: function(){  return 10; }
};

alert(obj) //20
console.log(obj) //Object {toString: function, valueOf: function}
```

unlike alert(obj) why console.log(obj) shows object structure instead of return value of toString()??

In both scenario expecting string text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alert() return different from console.log()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909006/alert-return-different-from-console-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only for the good of debugging. 
Would like to to see obj.toString() in console? Use:

```
Console.count(obj); //also will show how many times obj has been invoked
```

Usefull links:

1. [Firebug Console API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API)
2. [Chrome Console API](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api)
3. [Mozilla Dev Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

Answer (score 1):

console.log intended for debugging, and alert intended for showing text, so alert seek toString function if it exists then show it result, instead it will show [Object object].

Comment: That I agree but why console.log() does not call toString()

Comment: Because it's more useful for debugging to have the full object structure.

Comment: console.log(new String("hello")); //String {0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", length: 5} 

console.log(String("hello"));  //hello

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get text in console then just add empty string like bellow

```
console.log(obj + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the words of [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909006/alert-return-different-from-console-log/3909043#3909043), the method

> `alert()` converts the object passed to it into a string using the object's `toString()` method [whereas] `console.log()` is not only used to display a simple string but it can also allow you to interact with the object passed to it.

Also  `console.log()` is used for debugging. In the words of [Jan Hančič](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log/4539270#4539270),

> You can for instance log something to the console when something happens.

You use `console.log` to view full object structure.