# Accesing toString() Object method inside console.log

Tags: javascript, console, tostring

Refering to this post : [Why console.log(obj) show structure of obj instead of return value of toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347979/why-console-logobj-show-structure-of-obj-instead-of-return-value-of-tostring)

I have figured out that this piece of code will log the value returned by `toString()` method of `Obj`

```js
class Obj {
  constructor(){
    this.prop = 'a property';
  }
  toString(){
    return 'This is toString method of an instance of Obj and I have ' + this.prop;
  }
}

console.log(new Obj() + "");
```

**Is there another approach to do that ?**

Comment: Why don't you just do `(new Obj()).toString()` if you want the `toString` method to be called?

Comment: I forget to say that I want simplest/less code approach. In fact, what I wanted to show is that ES6 template literals call toString() method of passed objects.

Comment: Also, `console.log(String(new Obj))`. Or you do `const logString = compose(console::bind, String)`

Answer (score 0):

With new ES6 template literals, this becomes simplest :

```js
class Obj {
  constructor(){
    this.prop = 'a property';
  }
  toString(){
    return 'This is toString method of an instance of Obj and I have ' + this.prop;
  }
}

console.log(`${new Obj()}`);
```

`${new Obj()}` will call `toString` method of `Obj`.

Comment: That's actually longer than what the OP had, and much less convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But I don't understand why is this not convenient?

Comment: It does look much stranger and more complicated than the simple string concatenation, at least in my eyes. It's less convenient to type and to visually parse. It would be fine if there was any text in the template literal, but like this it is not a good solution.

Comment: You're right with this. I just discover this behaviour with objects by chance experiencing with ES6 features and I wanted to post here, so i didn't add more flourishes to the string logged. I thought this was strange too. But I think, once known, is not so strange. "Calling an object in a template literal returns the string of its toString() method".

Comment: I didn't mean that the behaviour of objects in template strings is strange (it's quite reasonable given how they work), but that I find it strange to see them used for this.

Comment: Sorry for misundestand you! So I'll take into account that and I'll avoid to use the template literals for doing this. Thank you for clarify my mind. =)

Answer (score 0):

Objects have string version set '[object Object]' as default; You can change it by overriding the `toString` method (in a class for example). If you pass console.log(new Obj()) it will simply output the object with its properties (because you passed Object type to the console.log). If you add `'' + ...` it will convert the object to the string, because it has higher precedence. And how do you convert object to string? Well, by calling its `toString()` method, which you can override and output some text like in your code.